# How to control the styles of many elements in React at one time?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a simple game, like this -
[game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgnIc.png)

When you hover a square, it turns blue, if hover again, it turns white.
For this aim I just add styles for event.targer on hover

```
const handleMouseEnter = (e) => {
    const hoveredDiv = e._targetInst.pendingProps.value;
    e.target.className = 'blue'
    if (hoveredSquares.includes(hoveredDiv)) {
      dispatch(actions.removeFromHovered(hoveredDiv))
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    } else {
      dispatch(actions.addToHovered(hoveredDiv))
      e.target.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
  }
```

The problem is, when I change a game mode, for example, 10*10, I need to make white all squares.
It is like restart a game, but already hovered squares a still blue of course.
Below is my code for squares

```
const generateSquares = () => {
 if (!currentMode || currentMode === 0) {
  return
 }
 const array = Array.from(Array(currentMode), () => Array(currentMode).fill(currentMode))

 return (
  <Box style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
    {array.map((rowEl, rowIndex) => {
      return (
        <Box
          key={rowIndex}
        >
          {rowEl.map((_, colIndex) => {
            return (
              <Box
                value={`row ${rowIndex + 1} col ${colIndex + 1}`}
                onMouseEnter={e => handleMouseEnter(e)}
                key={colIndex}
              ></Box>
            )
          })}
        </Box>
      )
    })}
  </Box>
)
```

}
In Vanilla JS I would use querySelectorAll.
How to control the styles of many elements in React at one time? Preferable using hooks.
Thanks

Comment: I found a solution, giving id and ref for parent Box element. Then I use ref.current.querySelectorAll('div'), and work with it as in vanilla JS. Is it good practice in React?

Answer (score 0):

You can create Base square component. After that each element has to have state.

```
const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false)
return <Square
 onMouseEnter={() => setIsHovered(true)}
 onMouseLeave={() => setIsHovered(false)}
 className={isHovered ? blue : white} />
```

When you have to change game then you need to rerender all your components, and states will be refreshed.